# How to include Point Cloud Library in an Android Studio project

Tags: android, c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to use PCL functions in our Android application to analyze point clouds captured by Google Tango hardware. I have already prototyped what I would like PCL to do on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine in C++ and I'm looking to bring the functionality to an Android application.

I have tried using this guide to build PCL for Android using CMake
https:://www.hirotakaster.com/weblog/how-to-build-pcl-for-android-memo/
The build succeeds and I am able to generate the following .a files for PCL

[build folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJBec.png)

[generated .a files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmlSd.png)

How can I either add this compiled library to Android Studio or make it so Android Studio is able to build this itself using CMake?

Comment: Currently I'm stuck here: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/wiki/Android